# How to make local test with okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I am learning okhttp and I want to make a test with local json file in my computer or android device. But I don't know how to access local file as url string to call the function.
Like this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File testJson = new File(sdcard, "test.json");
HttpUtils.HttpGet(testJson., mCallback);

public class HttpUtils {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpUtils";

    private static final OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();

    public static void HttpGet(String url, Callback callback) {
        //创建一个Request
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        //创建一个Call
        Call call = mClient.newCall(request);
        //请求加入调度
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: String url = "file://" + testJson.getAbsoluthePath();. But i think that okhttp will not honor your try.

Comment: If you want to do local tests then install a local webserver like NanoHttpD to serve your files. There are also such webservers available in play store.

Comment: @greenapps What's the difference between NanoHttpD and MockWebServer?

Comment: I do not know MockWebServer. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use MockWebServer to serve content you load from a file.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

```
  MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

  // Schedule some responses.
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("hello, world!"));
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("sup, bra?"));
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("yo dog"));

  // Start the server.
  server.start();

  // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
  HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");
```

Comment: What does:   "Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests" mean?  It looks like your are "telling" the server what the URL is.  I did this and it hit the REAL endpoint.  How do you make your code hit the new endpoint?

Comment: I have an article with an extended explanation. It might help you “Testing your Network logic” by Marcel Pintó https://link.medium.com/w86h0dkqnW

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to abstract your http client by some interface and create two implementation - one using OkHTTP and another - simply reading file.